# ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido

Tags: php, html, mysql

mucho gusto.
soy nuevo en la programación y estoy creando mi primera pagina web.
Tuve varios errores pero los pude solucionar yo solo, pero ahora este error no me deja continuar con lo quiero.
Alguien sabrá como solucionarlo?

[image]

```
***Este es mi codigo:

    <?php
    
    class Conexion {
    
        private static $conexion;
    
        public static function abrir_conexion() {
            if (!isset(self::$conexion)) {
                try {
                    include_once 'config.inc.php';
    
                    self::$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=$nombre_sevidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos', $nombre_usuario , $password);
                    self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                    
                    print 'CONEXION ABIERTA';
                } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    print "ERROR: " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br>";
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
    public static function  cerrar_conexion() {
        if(isset(self::$conexion)) {
            self::$conexion = null;
            print 'CONEXION CERRADA';
        }
    }
    public static function obtener_conexion() {
        return self::$conexion;
    }
    }***
```

Tambien dejo esto por si sirve de algo:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás usando comillas sencillas en el `new PDO(`. Intenta pasando ese string de conexión pero con comillas dobles (y asumiendo que hay dos variables definidas cuyos valores quieres colocar en la cadena: `$nombre_sevidor` y `$nombre_base_datos`).

Comment: No es lo mismo. Con comillas dobles, donde está puesto `$nombre_servidor`, se reemplazaría con el valor que tenga una variable de ese nombre (lo mismo con la otra variable). Con comillas sencillas **no hay reemplazo de valores** (ni si quiera de caracteres especiales como \n). Mi suposición al ver el código del OP es que las variables están definidas y que desea colocar esos valores en la cadena. Si usa comillas sencillas, eso no sucederá.